# How to statically compile an SDL game on Windows with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, sdl, static-linking

I downloaded the latest SDL HG from http://www.libsdl.org/ and compiled them using VS2010. And everything is working, but the dynamic linking is inconvenient.
I changed the project properties (in SDL HG) to static compilation, but now in projects (that use these libraries) are a lot of mistakes linker "unresolved external symbol".
How to correctly compile a library?

Answer (score 2):

If you want statically compile SDL in VS2010 you must change type of configuration from *dll* to *lib* and set all dependency in "Librarian" (for *lib* configuration) as in "Linker" (for *dll* configuration).
E.g. from my SDL_VS2010.vcxproj

```
<Lib>
  <AdditionalDependencies>winmm.lib;imm32.lib;version.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
</Lib>
<Lib>
  <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(DXSDK_DIR)\lib\x86</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
</Lib>
<Lib>
  <IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>true</IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>
  <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
  <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
</Lib>
<ProjectReference>
  <LinkLibraryDependencies>false</LinkLibraryDependencies>
</ProjectReference>
```